# Should i store file names in Java Enum or properties file

Tags: java, rest

I want to store file names, which keep on changing as the new files get added. I am looking for a minimum change in server code later when there is a need to support a new 'file' The thought I have is to store them either in properties file or as Java enum, but still thinking which is a better approach.

I am using REST and having 'file type' in the URL.
Example rest url:

**hostname/file-content/TYPE**

where value of TYPE could be any of these:  standardFileNames1,standardFileNames2,randomFileName1,randomFileName2

I have used TYPE to group the files, so as to minimize the change in url when a new file is added. Dont want to have file names in the URL due to security issues.

my thought goes like this:

### having as ENUM:

```
public enum FileType  
{
    standardFileNames1("Afile_en", "Afile_jp"),
    standardFileNames2("Bfile_en","Bfile_jp"),
    randomFileName1("xyz"),
    randomFileName2("abc"),
    ...
    ...
}
```

### having as properties file:

```
standardFileNames1=Afile_en,Afile_jp
standardFileNames2=Bfile_en,Bfile_jp
randomFileName1=xyz 
randomFileName2=abc
```

I know having this in properties will save build efforts on every change, but still want to know your views to figure out best solution with all considerations.

Thanks!
Akhilesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I often use property file + enum combination. Here is an example:

public enum Constants {
    PROP1,
    PROP2;

    private static final String PATH            = "/constants.properties";

    private static final Logger logger          = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Constants.class);

    private static Properties   properties;

    private String          value;

    private void init() {
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new Properties();
            try {
                properties.load(Constants.class.getResourceAsStream(PATH));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Unable to load " + PATH + " file from classpath.", e);
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        value = (String) properties.get(this.toString());
    }

    public String getValue() {
        if (value == null) {
            init();
        }
        return value;
    }

}
Now you also need a property file (I ofter place it in src, so it is packaged into JAR), with properties just as you used in enum. For example:

constants.properties:

#This is property file...
PROP1=some text
PROP2=some other text
Now I very often use static import in classes where I want to use my constants:

import static com.some.package.Constants.*;
And an example usage

System.out.println(PROP1);

Source:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908973/java-property-file-as-enum
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to keep in properties or config file and write a generic code to get the file list and parse in java. So that whenever a new file comes, there will be no change on server side rather you will add an entry to the properties or config file.