# How to change enumeration values based on system environment properties

Tags: java, enumeration

I have enumeration values like `Type(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` but my database entries have different type values in **development** `Type(12, 13, 14, 15, 16)` and in **staging** `Type(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

Now I can't change enumeration values in development because a lot of records created using Type values. So I need to set up enumeration values **Type** based on the **system environment properties**.

Sample Code:

```
public enum Type {

    JACKET(1, "Jacket"),
    DRESS(2, "Dress"),
    SCARF(3, "Scarf"),
    SHIRT(4, "Shirt");

private int id;
    private String name;

    Type(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static Type getById(int id) {
        Type categoryType = null;
        switch (id) {
            case 1:
                categoryType = JACKET;
                break;
            case 2:
                categoryType = DRESS;
                break;
            case 3:
                categoryType = SCARF;
                break;
            case 4:
                categoryType = SHIRT;
                break;
        }

        return categoryType;
    }
```

Is this possible to work enumeration values using System environment properties?

Comment: When you say "enumeration values", do you mean you have an `enum` type that you've given a `value` property?

Comment: Yes @KevinAnderson updated sample code

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909375/1776132

Comment: @Smile the answer doesn't mention environment like development/staging. How do I retrieve based on environments?

Comment: Have different property files for different environments

Comment: I don't need to get the value from properties file instead of any other solution there?

Comment: @dwayneJohn We will not be able to change the enum because, enum are static and final